# Weird output for echo and print_r

Tags: php

I haver discovered some weird behavior and cannot explain what is going on:

```
$e = 3;
echo "with array " . print_r($e);
```

gives:

```
3with array 1
```

why?

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: echo "with array " . print_r($e,**1**);

Comment: Execute `print_r($e)` displays `3` and returns a boolean `true`, which is then concatenated with the string literal `"with array "`, and the result of that is echoed, so also displayed as `with array 1`

Comment: Intersting question, I faced similar question that bringed me here.

Answer (score 5):

Concatenation is done before any output so:

```
echo "with array " . print_r($e);
```

is

1. Get result of `print_r`. `print_r` prints `3` and [returns `TRUE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#refsect1-function.print-r-returnvalues).
2. `with array` string concatenated with `TRUE`. And string representation of `TRUE` is `1`.
3. Summary: string to output is `3with array 1`

If you want `print_r` to **return** value instead of printing it - use it's second parameter:

```
echo "with array " . print_r($e, true);  // `with array 3`
```